# How to set the number of replicas properly when I try to start a TDengine cluster?

Tags: high-availability, tdengine

I was wondering how to set the **replica** parameter properly when start a TDengine cluster to balance the storage and high availability? According to documentation of TDengine, default value of **replica** is 1 which means no copies for each **vnode** (vGroup size should be 1 as well), and the **replica**  can be dynamically changed to maintain a high avilability of the cluster. However, the extra vnode copies have to be generated physically when starting up multi-replica. So the problem rise up, how should a real company determine the value of **replica** to increase availability without taking up too much overhead(storage and performance) when using TDengine cluster?

Answer (score 1):

**replica** means keeping a copy of the same data on multiple machines that are connected via a network. There are reasons you want to replicate data:

- To keep data geographically close to your users (and thus reduce latency)
- To allow the system to continue working even if some of its parts have failed (and thus increase availability)
- To scale out the number of machines that can serve read queries (and thus increase read throughput)

referred from DDIA